# Multiple lightboxes on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I'm making a onepage website for dog breeding company. I have 6 different dogs with 4 pictures of each dog. I want to have 6 diffferent lightboxes, each for every dog.
[Here is a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnVpY.jpg)

I'm quite familliar with html and css, but not quite with jquery or javascript so please help :)

Comment: Please add the code you have tried into the question.

Comment: can you write code here?

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a group name: `<a href='#' rel='group1'>...</a>`

You can add the group name to each link. Als long a goup has the same name the lightbox will see it as one group. Example:

```
<div class='dog1'>
<a href='#' rel='group1'>...</a>
<a href='#' rel='group1'>...</a>
<a href='#' rel='group1'>...</a>
</div>

<div class='dog2'>
<a href='#' rel='group2'>...</a>
<a href='#' rel='group2'>...</a>
<a href='#' rel='group2'>...</a>
</div>
```